# Save a UIView that contains a UILabel,UIImageView and UITableView as PDF in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pdf

My iOS app saves the selected contact details as PDF and displays it in a WebView.
 My View shows the selected contacts image (in UIImage), name (in UILabel) and other details like phone numbers (in UITableView).
Now, I need to save this view as a PDF and see it in another View.
The method `createPDFfromUIView` that I use now saves my View as PDF.

But I can't see the whole table view in my PDF.
I need to scroll to see the whole table view.
How can I resolve this?

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
     // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425271/how-to-capture-the-whole-tableview-as-an-image-create-a-pdf-from-it-and-email

Comment: @New16 This contains just a tableView.I need to incorporate a label and an image view too before saving as pdf.How do i do that?

Comment: Take the `layer` property of the main `UIView` they're part of instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it!

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
```

{
    CGRect priorBounds = self.contactDetails.bounds;
    CGSize fittedSize = [self.contactDetails sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, self.contactDetails.contentSize.height)];
    self.contactDetails.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);

```
CGRect pdfPageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 30, 312, 800); // Change this as your need
NSMutableData *pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), _detailView.bounds);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, _detailView.bounds, nil);
{

    int page = 1;
    for (CGFloat pageOriginY = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height)
    {

        if(page == 1)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(_detailView.bounds, nil);

            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            {


                [_contactImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake( 200, 10, _contactImage.bounds.size.width, _contactImage.bounds.size.height)];
                NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                             NSFontAttributeName   : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20],
                                             NSStrokeWidthAttributeName    : @(0),
                                             NSStrokeColorAttributeName    : [UIColor blackColor]
                                             };
                [_contactName.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(30 , 50) withAttributes:attributes];


                CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 130);
                [self.contactDetails.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];


            } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

        }
        else
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(_detailView.bounds, nil);
            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            {
                CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY);
                [self.contactDetails.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

            } CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        }
        page++;
    }

} UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

self.contactDetails.bounds = priorBounds; // Reset the tableView


// Use the pdfData to
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
NSString* filePathPDF = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPdf.pdf"]; //Add the file name
BOOL written = [pdfData writeToFile:filePathPDF atomically:YES];
```

}